# My css and html are not working to put my code on the same line

Tags: html

I have created two div tags. One containing /hello/ the other containing /world/. My issue is i want both of these to be on the same line so I put in the code display: inline, but that did not work. I also want /hello/ to have a background color of yellow. so I have tried giving them classes but that did not work either. Please simple answers because I am only 12

Comment: This question is not acceptable. Make a jsfiddle and post your code.

Comment: Did you create css rules [like here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp) for the classes you gave them?

Comment: yes I gave them css rules

Comment: See the demo I posted for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be messing up with class names or while importing the CSS files [Here is the example that works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/uvg1kfg4/)

See if this is what you want,

```
<div class="firstDiv">
    Hello
</div>
<div>
    World
</div>
```

And my CSS as,

```
div{
    display:inline;
}
.firstDiv{
    background-color: red
}
```

You can also try inline CSS to get the same effect,

```
<div style="display:inline;background-color:red">
        Hello
</div>

<div style="display:inline">
    World
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that really helped. I have been working at that for a while. I can not express my gratitude

Comment: You actually *can* express your graditude, by marking this answer as accepted and up voting it

Answer (score 0):

Div are block elements. Which means by default they will place on a new line. You will need to use css to make them display inline.

```
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:400px;"></div>
<div style="float:left; border:1px solid blue; width:200px; height:400px;"></div>
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2L878bcu/1/